# CSS how to auto adjust width img tag

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page that I need to show in a client mobile device.

In that HTML there is an `<img>` tag. Some images are too big and need to resize for mobile device screen.

So I tried to override CSS like this:

```
#content img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto  !important;;
}
```

But some images still have width > screen size.

So I tried this:

```
#content img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto  !important;;
}
```

But this way, every picture will be scale full width. (small picture scaled look so terrible)

I just want to apply for `<img>` tag where size of this image more than size of screen.

Comment: `max-width: 100vw;`, plus what you have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need add !important until you are going to override already existing css line.
So the code would be like this,

```
#content img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set a class(eg: myClass) for those images which you want to resize and set css for it

```
 #content img.myClass{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto  !important;;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width` instead of `width`.

```
 #content img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto  !important;
  }
```